# Python file upload to php Script

Tags: php, python

I'm currently trying to upload a file using a python script to a php server.

Unfortunately I always get an Error:

Python Code:

```
import requests,json
URL = '<Serverurl>.php'
myfile = '<uploaddir>\Bild.jpg'

files = {'upfile' : open(myfile, 'rb')}
r = requests.post(URL, files = files)

print(r.text)
```

PHP Code:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["upfile"])) {     
            $imageFile = fopen($_FILES["upfile"]["tmp_name"], "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $imageData = fread($imageFile, $_FILES["upfile"]["size"]);
            fclose($imageFile);
            //image processing follows here .. 
} else {
    echo "Error: no image found";
}
```

Error I receive from my python console: 
`"Unable to open file!`"

Php-Console Error:

```
'PHP message: PHP Warning:  fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/vcap/app/htdocs/index.php on line 18\n'
```

I hope someone has an idea to solve this problem. 
Greetings

Comment: Things to double check: File 'myfile' exists (maybe relative path is wrong, go for absolute), do you have permission to read it? i.e. can you `cat`/`less` it?

Comment: "Unable to open file!"... 3 possibilities: 1. file does not exist, 2. the file path is not correct, 3. python has no read rights on this file

Comment: Argh. Used another file -> Worked. Thank you!