# PHP move uploaded files to directory

Tags: python, php

I am posting files from python script to PHP from where I want to store them in a directory. I am scanning whole system for **.rtx** files and sending all of them to PHP.
Below is my python script.

```
 url = 'http://localhost:9090/project/php/new.php'
    driveStr = subprocess.check_output("fsutil fsinfo drives")
    driveStr = driveStr.decode("utf-8")
    driveStr = driveStr.strip().lstrip('Drives: ')
    drives = driveStr.split()
    print(drives)
    mylist = []
    for drive in drives:
    
        if os.path.isdir(drive):
            p = os.walk(drive)
            for i , dirs , files in p :
                for filename in files :
                    if filename.endswith('rtx'):
    
                        file_path = pathlib.PurePath(i, filename)
                        print(file_path)
    
                        mylist.append(file_path)
                  

  upload_file = [
                    ("rtx_file" , (filename , open ( file_path , 'rb' ) , 'text/rtx'))
                ]
                response = requests.post ( url , files = upload_file )
```

And below is my PHP script here I am receiving those files and moving them to directory.

```
    <?php


if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    $target_path = "C:\wamp64\www\project\php\upload";
    
    $target_path = $target_path . '/' . basename( $_FILES['files']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['files']['name'])." has been uploaded";
    }
    else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    

    
    
}
else
{
    echo "no file uploaded";
}

?>
```

My issue is that it is not storing those files into specified directory. If anyone has any idea kindly guide me what is wrong. Thank You
I follow this below link to implement my program.
[Python file upload to php Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671975/python-file-upload-to-php-script)

Comment: You should post your php server's logs and python's request logs, or show the error tips. And you should print some debug logs.

Comment: @VictorLee PHP server's log `error_log => no value => no value`   debug logs                                  `g = logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
print(g)`       and it is showing None

Comment: Have you confirmed that the files are available within the `$_FILES` array and not the `$_POST` array?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes files are available within $_FILES

Comment: So a `var_dump($_FILES)` or `print_r($_FILES,true)` will show correct info abut uploaded files and include name,size,type,error etc for each?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes

Comment: `$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['files']['name']);` needs a forward slash before the filename ... `$target_path = $target_path . '/' . basename( $_FILES['files']['name']);`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I have changed $target_path but still it is not storing files in specified folder.

Comment: the Python script is sending multiple files or only a single one each time the PHP script is invoked? If there are multiple you need to process the `$_FILES` array differently and iterate through each uploaded file and save individually.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I am sending files in a loop and on every iteration it sends only one file.

Comment: have you set correct permissions so that you can write to that particular directory?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius yes

Comment: so - this was a Python issue rather than PHP?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234280/discussion-between-programmer-and-professor-abronsius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in requests.you can upload files by this.below is an example.you can read more on [requests upload](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)

```py
upload_file = [
    ("rtx_file",(filename,open(file_path,'rb'),'text/rtx'))
]
requests.post(url,files=upload_file)
```

if you have further question.print the requests response object.and if possible write some log in php(not echo,echo only print the output the to client).

Comment: When I print response of requests object it is showing `<Response [200]>`

Comment: modify php add `else` to `if(isset($_FILES['files']))`.in `else` section `echo "no file uploaded"`.then in python `r = requests.post(url,files=upload_file)` `print(r.text)`.you should try to know your code run step.

Comment: when I did `print (r.text)` It show this in output  `no file uploadedArray
(
)`

Comment: can you update your question with the newest code

Comment: I have updated my question with newest code

Comment: sorry.My mistak.change `("rtx_file",(filename,open(file_path,'rb'),'text/rtx'))` to `("files",(filename,open(file_path,'rb'),'text/rtx'))`.if not work.try to `print_r($_FILES);` in `else` section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234276/discussion-between-programmer-and-nay).